# Change text to Bold in Outlook Message Body

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

please help me with following.
I'm working on creating and modifying outlook messages from template. I need to change some text to Bold.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string CustomerName = node.SelectSingleNode("CustomerName").InnerText;

    string ReportName = node.SelectSingleNode("ReportName").InnerText + ".pdf";

    Outlook.Application mailApplication = new Outlook.Application();

    Outlook.MailItem mail = mailApplication.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"d:\Friday Report\#TEMPLATES\template.oft") as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
    mail.Attachments.Add(@"d:\Friday Report\" + ReportName);
    mail.Subject = "Application Packaging – Weekly Summary";
    CustomerName = "<b>" + CustomerName + "</b> ";
    string body = mail.Body;
    string new_body = body.Replace("CustomerName", CustomerName );
    mail.Body = new_body;
    mail.Display(true);
    mail.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
}
```

[image: Screenshot with breakpoint] 
[image: Mail Display Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use HTML in your email, you need to set the [`HTMLBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.htmlbody%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property instead of `Body`:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string CustomerName = node.SelectSingleNode("CustomerName").InnerText;

    string ReportName = node.SelectSingleNode("ReportName").InnerText + ".pdf";

    Outlook.Application mailApplication = new Outlook.Application();

    Outlook.MailItem mail = mailApplication.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"d:\Friday Report\#TEMPLATES\template.oft") as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
    mail.Attachments.Add(@"d:\Friday Report\" + ReportName);
    mail.Subject = "Application Packaging – Weekly Summary";
    CustomerName = "<b>" + CustomerName + "</b> ";
    string body = mail.Body;
    string new_body = body.Replace("CustomerName", CustomerName );
    mail.HTMLBody = new_body;
    mail.Display(true);
    mail.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
}
```

You should use valid HTML, though, by surrounding your mail with `<html><body>{your message}</body></html>`

Comment: Thanx, pal! Very helpful for me. 
One more question. Now i loose all formating from my template. I think thats cause i put body into string. Can i change the first element of email body, with any other method?
Or it would be easier to configure new "string" body with tags? 
@Camilo Terevinto

Comment: @Tosik I am not sure why you'd lose the formatting. Perhaps you have some invalid HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (see screen shot below the code)

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using outlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace z_Console_Scratch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mailItem.Subject = "test subject";
            mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This is the <strong>funky</strong> message body</body></html>";
            mailItem.Display(false);

        }


    }

}
```

Note: This works as well: `mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This is the <b>funky</b> message body</body></html>";`

**Screen Shot**

[image: image of email body showing bolded text]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: modified answer to show working code